# how does whats app keep the account detail(Phone number) after clearing the cache and data

Tags: android, caching

i wanna authenticate using phone number in my app like whats app so Please tell me how does whats app keep the registered phone number even if i clear the the cache and data from setting and change the sim from phone.

How does it validate the user after clearing cache and data because all application data get deleted if we do so.

Its very important for me .

Comment: May be stored in a file on disk.

Comment: @Archie.bpgc how does it maintain the security level of it.?

Comment: Whatsapp maintains it's chat data in SD card which can also be ported also devices (same platform). So you can maintain data in SD Card / somewhere else in FS. App Data is stored in `/data/app_package/` directory. May be it keeps data somewhere else.. you can do the same too

Comment: For security, AFAIK Whatsapp chats are encrypted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We will be creating account with the number , and the account will be saved in the database . The account will only be removed after user removes it explicitly or uninstalls the application . Check [Sync adapter](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html) and [Account Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html).

Even Gmail , FB , Twitter use this concept they will create account and use sync adapters to periodically sync the data.

Why clearing data does not remove account ?

It is (DB where account related info is saved) not part of settings application

change the sim from phone ?
The original sim info will be saved and related to account.

Comment: But i wanna do authentication like whatsapp does, on behalf of phone number.

Comment: We can do that , use the same logic create an account with account name as your phone number  and account type as your application name.

Answer (score 0):

It probably validates the user via [Android Device ID](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID)

Comment: @Android Every Android Device has an ID which is know as Device ID. Visit Link provided in answer

Comment: @Android Its a unique identifier, allows app developers to identify a particular device at the hardware level. As SimpleGuy said.

Comment: @Android so even though you clean your device, on the whatsapp server end they may have your Device ID linked to your phone number you once had registered with them.

Comment: @ErrolGreen 
How does it authenticate using device ID?

Comment: @Android I'm not entirely sure how Whatsapp authentication works.

Comment: @ErrolGreen how should i save the device id file  in location which doesbot  get accessed by unrooted phone

Comment: @Android well you could save it In the database. Along with the users information. However Rahuls answer seems a little more feasible. If security is  issue for you, I'd highly recommend making an account that they  authenticate with, then after clearing device they would have to authenticate once again.